# Inspecting individual Polygons of MultiPolygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, multipart, multi-polygon, singlepart

Using QGIS's `Identify` results, I can highlight and inspect an individual 'feature', in this case a country geometry. In reality, the geometry is a `MultiPolygon` and I would like to inspect individual polygons one by one (in this case islands) which are part of the larger feature/MultiPolygon. How can this be done?

[image: QGIS Identify Feature screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert your MultiPolygon to single Polygons using the ["Multipart to singleparts"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) from `Menu Vector > Geometry Tools > Multipart to singleparts`. Than use the `Identify` tool again.

It will generate a new (additional) layer with each part as a separate feature. Your original MultiPolygon layer will be kept unchanged.

Comment: Worth noticing that because the multipolygon was originally one feature all the singlepart polygons will have the same attribute values than the multipolygon.

Comment: Indeed! The derived values in the identify tool (like measurements for area etc.) will return values for the individual singlepart features.